# Json Data is not displayed on table using php json

Tags: php

i am tring to displayed the json data in to the table but it didn't show what tried so far i attached below of code.what the error when the page is loaded i attached the image below.if i check at the console.log all data is displayed. not passing at the table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRHNu.jpg)

**Table**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table class="table table-striped" id="mytable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ProductID</th>
        <th>Productname</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script>
  function getProducts() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'cart.php',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data) {
        //   console.log(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          console.log(data);
          var id = data[i].id;
          var product_name = data[i].product_name;
          var price = data[i].price;

          $('#mytable tbody tr').after(
            '<tr> ' +
            '<td>' + product_name + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + price + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + "<input type = 'text' id='pname'/>" + '</td>' +
            '</tr>');
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

cart.php

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("select id,product_name,price from cart order by id DESC ");
$stmt->bind_result($id,$product_name,$price);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $output[] = array ("id"=>$id, "product_name"=>$product_name,"price"=>$price);
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
}
$stmt->close();

//}
```

Comment: after `dataType : 'json',` add `encode:true` and test again, I t would be wise also to show your `cart.php`

Comment: ___Silly Question Probably___ Is your javascript code wrapped in `<script>` tags?

Comment: encode:true   i did it is not working

Comment: ok sir i will show up cart.php page i edited above

Comment: And what about what @RiggsFolly asked?

Comment: .if i check at the console.log all data is displayed. not passing at the table is it correct sir $('#mytable tbody tr').after(

Comment: How about using `forEach`

Comment: forEach  how to write and display data sir.can you write sir

Comment: 0: {id: 17, product_name: "tv", price: "12000"}
1: {id: 16, product_name: "tv", price: "12000"}
2: {id: 15, product_name: "caps", price: "150"}    json output displayed successfulled i checked through console.log how to pass into the table

Comment: @PrabigaDuraisamy check the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function to loop through the results and also on `$('#mytable tbody tr').after()` you need to remove the `tr` as there's no `tr` element in your body it should be `$('#mytable tbody').after(....)` then when you done run the function by calling `getProducts()`

Your code should look like :

```
 <script>
      function getProducts() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'cart.php',
          dataType: 'JSON',
          success: function(data) {
             data.forEach(function(element) {

               var id = element.id;
               var product_name = element.product_name;
                var price = element.price;

               $('#mytable tbody').after(
                '<tr> ' +
                '<td>' + id + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + product_name + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + price + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + "<input type = 'text' id='pname'/>" + '</td>' +
                '</tr>');

             });
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
          }
        });
      }
      getProducts();
    </script>
```

Comment: Glad I could help